# Java: copy a single array from a 2d array

Tags: java, arrays

While I was browsing answers here, I read that

> "Java does not have true 2-dimensional arrays; it has arrays of
>   arrays, so x[rows][cols] is an array x of rows arrays of cols elements
>   (i.e. x[rows] is an array of arrays)."

That seems like good news for me, as I want to create a single 1D array by copying a "row" from a 2D array. What is the correct syntax to call a specific array from P, my 2D array? Essentially:

```
new double[] row1 = P[row];
```

Or do I have to loop through the row I want to copy? I have tried the above code and several similar approaches. All receive an error of "Array dimension missing".

Comment: Have you tried using this (kind of) code? If yes what were your results?

Comment: @UnholySheep Yes sir, I have tried a few different things along those lines. They all result in a compiler message of "Array dimension missing".

Comment: Now that is more along the lines of how you ask on SO. So, why did you write `new` at the beginning? Why do you think that should be there? (It shouldn't and is the cause of your error)

Comment: @UnholySheep Errors gone. Thank you. I did it that way because I've never declared a new array without using the word new, and did what I do normally. I have edited the question to include the detail that I tried the code that I went through the effort of typing into the question initially, as well as the fact that it received an error message (surprisingly enough I wouldn't be asking if it had worked). I do understand that some people might not be able to arrive at that conclusion on their own. Should I delete my question, as it was a "typo", or do you think it might be helpful to others?

Comment: In your code you aren't declaring a new array though, it's a reference to another array (as explained in the answers below). That's why you don't need to `new` anything (it also means that any modifications you do in `row1` will be also done in `P[row]`. If you were to create a copy that would not be the case.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a **reference** to a row, you can use `double[] selectedRow = P[rowToSelect]`. The `new` keyword in your code is misplaced. If you want a *real* copy or better known as **deep copy**, you can use:

```
double[] selectedRow = new double[P[rowToSelect].length];
System.arraycopy(P[rowToSelect], 0, selectedRow, 0, P[rowToSelect].length);`
```

Comment: The "new" was the source of all the errors. Thank you for the additional information on "deep copy", that's great!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use a reference, rather than a copy:

```
final double[] row1 = P[row];
```

However, if you need a copy, you can do this:

```
final double[] row1 = Arrays.copy(P[row], P[row].length);
```

This of-course assumes `P` is of type `double[][]` and `row` is an `int` which is within the valid index range.

Comment: @wesleyNeill Its the duty of the comment author to provide comments as comments and answers as answers.  However, you can always ask the comment author to re-post their comment as an answer, and then upvote/accept that answer.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you are copying **reference**, instead of an **array**:

```
new double[] row1 = P[row];
```

In case of modification any of them, both would show the result.
To copy the **array** you can use static method **copyOf** from **Arrays** class:

```
double[][] source = new double[rows][cols];
double[] destination = Arrays.copyOf(source[rowNumber], source[rowNumber].length);
```

The other way of doing this is by using static method **arraycopy** from **System** class:

```
System.arraycopy( source[rowNumber], 0, destination, 0, source[rowNumber].length );
```

And the lastone is by invoking **clone** method:

```
double[] destination = source[rowNumber].clone();
```